# I am parsing the html and I dont want include header img tags of header element

Tags: html, parsing, xpath, html-parsing, xquery

Following is the code which is written in PHP function. Right now I am getting all the img's src of the whole HTML. I just want to have the img tag of the whole html except the tags present in header.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($data);
$finder = new DomXPath($doc);
$nodes_images = $finder->query("//img/@src");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the HTML5 `header` element then using `//img[not(ancestor::header)]/@src` should select all `src` attributes of all `img` elements that are not descendants of the `header` element. I don't know, however, how well the libxml2 based HTML parsing used by PHP's loadHTML supports parsing HTML5.

Comment: I want to get the src of all the img tags of html except those which are present in <header> element. The header includes menu, logo and social media icons.